# Does pytest require a special setting when running from within my virtual environment?

Tags: python-3.x, django, unit-testing, pytest

I'm using Python 3.7 with Django 3.  I want to use pytest to write some unit tests but am getting a strange configuration error.  Here's a basic unit test I have ...

```
import pytest
from django.test import TestCase
from .factories import CoopTypeFactory, CoopFactory, AddressFactory, StateFactory, EmailContactMethodFactory, PhoneContactMethodFactory
from directory.models import Coop, CoopType
from directory.serializers import *


class SerializerTests(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        #management.call_command('loaddata', 'test_data.yaml', verbosity=0)
        pass

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_coop_type_create(self):
        """ Test coop serizlizer model """
        name = "Library"
        serializer_data = {
            "name": name,
        }

        serializer = CoopTypeSerializer(data=serializer_data)
        serializer.is_valid()
        print(serializer.errors)
        assert serializer.is_valid(), serializer.errors
        coop_type = serializer.save() 
        assert coop_type.name == name
```

But when I go to run the test, I get a configuration error, complaining about an undefined variable, "ERROR test_serializers.py - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured"

```
(venv) localhost:tests davea$ pytest test_serializers.py
============================================================= test session starts =============================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/tests
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                   

=================================================================== ERRORS ====================================================================
____________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_serializers.py _____________________________________________________
test_serializers.py:3: in <module>
    from .factories import CoopTypeFactory, CoopFactory, AddressFactory, StateFactory, EmailContactMethodFactory, PhoneContactMethodFactory
factories.py:3: in <module>
    from directory.models import CoopType, Coop, ContactMethod
../directory/models.py:5: in <module>
    from address.models import Address
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/address/models.py:162: in <module>
    class Country(models.Model):
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:107: in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:252: in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:134: in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:76: in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:61: in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
E   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
=========================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================
ERROR test_serializers.py - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. ...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================================== 1 error in 0.51s ===============================================================
(venv) localhost:tests davea$
```

I'm already running from within my virtual environment.  What else do I need to do to get pytest to run?

Comment: you will need `pytest-django` to run the test from Django framework.

Comment: I ran "pip3 install pytest-django" successfully but still get the error after.

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html

Comment: I'm pretty new to pytest, I'm not sure what you are asking me to do in the documentation that I haven't already done.

Comment: did you set up `pytest.ini` file? that what the documentation is for.